# Recursive reflect result in undesired data output

Tags: go

I am trying to construct a JSON object from a collection of structs. Because of the nesting I call my `convertStruct` functions recursively. It is really close to working 100%, however there is one part that I can't seem to figure out...

Here is the function:

```
func convertStruct(s interface{}) string {
    fmt.Println("interface: ", s) // Prints correct data

    fields := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    numFields := fields.NumField()
    values := reflect.ValueOf(s)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.WriteString("{\n")
    for colField := 0; colField < numFields; colField++ {
        field := fields.Field(colField)
        value := values.Field(colField)

        if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            str := fmt.Sprintf("\t%v: [\n", field.Name)
            buf.WriteString(str)
            if value.Len() > 0 {
                for fieldIndex := 0; fieldIndex < value.Len(); fieldIndex++ {
                    str := fmt.Sprintf("\t\t %v,\n", convertStruct(value.Index(fieldIndex)))
                    buf.WriteString(str)
                }
            }
            str = fmt.Sprintf("\t],\n")
            buf.WriteString(str)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("else:NOT a slice: ", field.Name, value) // Only prints correctly the first time
            str := fmt.Sprintf("\t%v: '%v',\n", field.Name, value)
            buf.WriteString(str)
        }
    }
    buf.WriteString("}")

    return buf.String()
}
```

The first time this function executes both `fmt.Println`s work properly, once it is recursively called, however, only the first one does.

The return value of this function is written to a file. In the file everything is correct except for what was processed during recursive execution.

Here is what the interface looks like:

```
type collection struct {
    id         string
    name       string
    databaseId string
    fields     []field
}
```

And here are what fields look like:

```
type field struct {
    id           string
    name         string
    fieldType    string
    collectionId string
}
```

Here is the code that uses `convertStruct`:

```
func buildCollection(dbId string, colName string, fields []field) {
    // Generate uuid to be used as collection ID
    colId := getUUID()

    // Create and open new collection file in the desired database directory
    filePath := fmt.Sprintf("./.minutesdb/databases/%v/collections/%v.mdb", dbId, colId)
    file, fileErr := os.Create(filePath)
    checkErr(fileErr)
    defer closeFile(file)

    // Create collection struct with empty fields slice
    colStruct := collection{
        id:         colId,
        name:       colName,
        databaseId: dbId,
        fields:     make([]field, 0),
    }

    for _, field := range fields {
        colStruct.fields = append(colStruct.fields, field)
    }

    // Convert collection struct and convert to JSON-like string
    colDataString := convertStruct(colStruct)
    _, writeStringErr := file.WriteString(colDataString)
    checkErr(writeStringErr)

    // Commit file data to disk
    syncErr := file.Sync()
    checkErr(syncErr)
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    id: 'b7fbda0e-2871-11eb-8aec-acde48001122',
    name: 'root',
    databaseId: 'b7f9d812-2871-11eb-8aea-acde48001122',
    fields: [
        {
            typ: '&{64 56 1143838361 7 8 8 25 0x10d38a0 0x11206b4 13088 34144}',
            ptr: '0xc0000de400',
            flag: '441',
        },
        {
            typ: '&{64 56 1143838361 7 8 8 25 0x10d38a0 0x11206b4 13088 34144}',
            ptr: '0xc0000de440',
            flag: '441',
        },
        {
            typ: '&{64 56 1143838361 7 8 8 25 0x10d38a0 0x11206b4 13088 34144}',
            ptr: '0xc0000de480',
            flag: '441',
        },
        {
            typ: '&{64 56 1143838361 7 8 8 25 0x10d38a0 0x11206b4 13088 34144}',
            ptr: '0xc0000de4c0',
            flag: '441',
        },
        {
            typ: '&{64 56 1143838361 7 8 8 25 0x10d38a0 0x11206b4 13088 34144}',
            ptr: '0xc0000de500',
            flag: '441',
        },
    ],
}
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: @MuffinTop just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) your fields so that [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) can properly access the values they hold.

```golang
type collection struct {
    Id         string
    Name       string
    DatabaseId string
    Fields     []field
}

type field struct {
    Id           string
    Name         string
    FieldType    string
    CollectionId string
}
```

Then, use [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) instead of your `convertStruct` function.

```golang
func buildCollection(dbId string, colName string, fields []field) {
    // Generate uuid to be used as collection ID
    colId := getUUID()

    // Create and open new collection file in the desired database directory
    filePath := fmt.Sprintf("./.minutesdb/databases/%v/collections/%v.mdb", dbId, colId)
    file, fileErr := os.Create(filePath)
    checkErr(fileErr)
    defer closeFile(file)

    // Create collection struct with empty fields slice
    colStruct := collection{
        Id:         colId,
        Name:       colName,
        DatabaseId: dbId,
        Fields:     fields,
    }

    err := json.NewEncoder(file).Encode(colStruct)
    checkErr(err)
    
    // Commit file data to disk
    syncErr := file.Sync()
    checkErr(syncErr)
}
```

---

If, however, you feel like you have to use your `convertStruct` function, go ahead, but you still need to **export** the fields, and you need to understand that [`(reflect.Value).Field()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field) and [`(reflect.Value).Index()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index) both return a `reflect.Value` *representation* of the value in that field or at that index. This, I'm sure you can see in the docs. So then, to get the actual, underlying value, you need to invoke the [`(reflect.Value).Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method.

And please note that `convertStruct` does not produce well formed json. There are too many commas and, it's using single quotes for strings. So you should either stop calling it json, or do it properly.

```golang
func convertStruct(s interface{}) string {
    fields := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    numFields := fields.NumField()
    values := reflect.ValueOf(s)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.WriteString("{\n")
    for colField := 0; colField < numFields; colField++ {
        field := fields.Field(colField)
        value := values.Field(colField)

        if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            str := fmt.Sprintf("\t%v: [\n", field.Name)
            buf.WriteString(str)
            if value.Len() > 0 {
                for fieldIndex := 0; fieldIndex < value.Len(); fieldIndex++ {
                    str := fmt.Sprintf("\t\t %v,\n", convertStruct(value.Index(fieldIndex).Interface()))
                    buf.WriteString(str)
                }
            }
            str = fmt.Sprintf("\t],\n")
            buf.WriteString(str)
        } else {
            str := fmt.Sprintf("\t%v: '%v',\n", field.Name, value.Interface())
            buf.WriteString(str)
        }
    }
    buf.WriteString("}")

    return buf.String()
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! I'm new to Go so I didn't know half that stuff lol thanks again